# Why does the code return false

Tags: php, joomla

I have a the following code which returns false even if I upload a file with valid extension ?

```
$file = JRequest::getVar('filename', null, 'files', 'array');

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

if(strtolower(JFile::getExt($file)) == 'pdf' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($file)) == 'gif' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($file)) == 'jpg' || strtolower(JFile::getExt($file)) == 'png') {
  // ..
}
else {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Will u remove strlower and try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JFile::getExt()` function of joomla API returns the extension of any file, but I think there is a bug, if your file has no extension, for example Readme files which do not have any extension, in that case it should return a null, but it returns the complete filepath.

So, instead we should use this better alternative

```
pathinfo ($file_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

[**Read more**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

[**Read this for eg**](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-filename-extension/) & [**This too**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214366/how-to-make-pathinfo-return-the-right-extension)

Comment: thanks for your kind help. well i got it working just by adding the entire code in the model. earlier i was validating it in the controller. i don't really understand the difference but its working